# For i.i.d. $X,Y\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$ we have $\max(X,Y)\sim \frac{(|X|+Y)}{\sqrt 2}.$

Tags: probability-theory

> **Problem.** Let $X,Y$ be independent and identically $\mathcal N(0,1)$ distributed random variables.
>   Then $$\max(X,Y)\sim \frac{(|X|+Y)}{\sqrt 2}.$$

**My attempt:** This is supposed to be an exercise on characteristic functions, so we can prove the claim using characteristic functions if we can show that $$\varphi_{\max(X,Y)}(t) = \varphi_{(|X|+Y)/\sqrt 2}(t)= \varphi_{|X|}(\sqrt 2 t)\cdot \varphi_Y(\sqrt 2 t) = \varphi_{|X|}(\sqrt 2 t) \cdot e^{-t^2} \quad(t\in \Bbb R).$$

But how can we compute the characteristic functions of $\max(X,Y)$ or $|X|$? To this end, I tried to figure out how they are distributed by direct computation:

$$\begin{eqnarray} P(|X|\leq t) &=&  P(X\leq t, X>0)+ P(-X\leq t, X<0)
\\&=& 2 P(0<X\leq t)
\\&=&2(\phi(t) - \phi(0))
\\&=& 2\phi(t)-1\end{eqnarray}$$ so that $|X| \sim 2X-1$. This gives that $\varphi_{|X|}(t)=e^{-it}\cdot e^{2t^2}$ and the claim rephrases to showing that $\varphi_{\max(X,Y)}(t) = e^{-it+t^2}$.

To find out how $\max(X,Y)$ is distributed, I computed $$\begin{eqnarray}P(\max(X,Y)\leq t) &=& P(X\leq t, X>Y) + P(Y\leq t, Y>X)
\\&=&2P(X\leq t, X>Y) \end{eqnarray}$$
and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Am I on the right track? How do I proceed in the above computation? Is there a simpler solution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: $\max(X,Y)\leq t\iff X\leq t\text{ and }Y\leq t$.
You made a mistake: $|X|$ and $2X-1$ don't have the same distribution. $2X-1$ is normally distributed (with mean $-1$ and variance $4$), whereas $|X|$ is positive a.s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most brutal (but effective) approach is to prove that $Z=\max(X,Y)$ and $W=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|X|+Y\right)$ have the same PDF. Let $f_X,f_Y,f_Z,f_W$ the PDFs of $X,Y,Z,W$, $\phi$ and $\Phi$ the PDF and CDF of the standard normal distribution. We have:
$$ \mathbb{P}[Z\leq t]=\mathbb{P}[X\leq t \wedge Y\leq t] =\Phi(t)^2.\tag{1}$$
On the other hand:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \mathbb{P}[Y+|X|\leq t\sqrt{2}] &=& \int_{-\infty}^{t\sqrt{2}}\phi(u)\int_{0}^{t\sqrt{2}-u}2\phi(v)\,dv\,du\\&=&\int_{-\infty}^{t\sqrt{2}}\phi(u)\left(2\,\Phi(t\sqrt{2}-u)-1\right)\,du\\&=&2\int_{-\infty}^{t\sqrt{2}}\phi(u)\,\Phi(t\sqrt{2}-u)\,du-\Phi(t\sqrt{2})\\&=&2\int_{-\infty}^{t\sqrt{2}}\Phi(u)\,\phi(t\sqrt{2}-u)\,du\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
hence you just need to apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to prove that $f_Z=f_W$.